# Facebook user id iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I wants get Facebook access_token and user id when user login first time in application. I already get the access token but struggling with Facebook user id.

Please provide  me help. how i get the user_id?

i getting the access_token in following method :

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {


_isExtendingAccessToken = NO;
_requestExtendingAccessToken = nil;
NSString* accessToken = [result objectForKey:@"access_token"];
NSString* expTime = [result objectForKey:@"expires_at"];

if (accessToken == nil || expTime == nil) {
    return;
}

self.accessToken = accessToken;


NSLog(@"access token is ---------->%@",self.accessToken);

//////.........
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try see at this [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/users.getInfo/) and use this code

```
for (NSDictionary* Info in result)
{
    NSString* uid = [Info objectForKey:@"uid"];
}
```

Hope will be a useful

Comment: you can after your: NSString* expTime = [result objectForKey:@"expires_at"];